# Вывод расписания

Tags: php

Мне нужно вывести уроки именно под тот день недели, который я беру из базы. Как это сделать?

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['date1'])) {
    $start        = strtotime($_POST["date1"]);
    $finish       = strtotime($_POST["date2"]);
    $arrayOfDates = array();
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $finish; $i += 86400) {
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode(".", date("Y.m.d", $i));
        $arrayOfDates[] = "$day.$month.$year";
    }
}
$dayweek = array(
    "0" => "Воскресенье",
    "1" => "Понедельник",
    "2" => "Вторник",
    "3" => "Среда",
    "4" => "Четверг",
    "5" => "Пятница",
    "6" => "Суббота"
);
$sql     = "SELECT r.predmet, o.ocenka FROM ocenki o, raspisanie r WHERE r.class=$klass";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $predmet        = $row["predmet"];
    $pr["$predmet"] = $row["ocenka"];
}

foreach ($arrayOfDates as $date) {
    $dnedeli = $dayweek[date("w", strtotime($date))];
    echo "<table width='300' border='1' style='display:inline-block;margin:20px 20px 0 0;'>";
    echo "<tr><th width='80%'>Предмет</th><th width='20%'>$date $dnedeli</th></tr>";
    foreach ($pr as $pr1 => $null) {
        echo "<tr><td>$pr1</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В нативной функции `date()` море возможностей. День недели определяется как `date('w', $timestamp);`
А вообще, мой Вам совет, не привязывайтесь к дню недели! В базе храните unix-timestamp, выборка будет проще, числовые значения легче сравнивать, можно легко вычислить любой диапазон дат.

Comment: Отписал, если у вас есть скайп можем там. Мой ник только не 294, а 194

Answer (score 1):

Непонятный вопрос какой-то. Допустим, имеем день недели понедельник, тогда $weekday=0, соответственно в воскресенье $weekday=6. В базе должно быть значение с датой, допустим, это будет поле `some_date` в таблице `raspisanie`. Тогда можно сделать запрос, возвращающий результаты в зависимости от дня недели, и выглядеть он будет примерно так:

```
$weekday = 0; //понедельник
$query = "select * from raspisanie where weekday(some_date) = '$weekday'";
// или в вашем случае, я полагаю:
$sql = "SELECT r.predmet, o.ocenka FROM ocenki o, raspisanie r WHERE r.class='$klass' and weekday(r.some_date) = '$weekday'";
```

А вообще, если хотите получить нужный вам ответ, добавьте в вопрос дополнительную информацию, хотя бы, где хранится дата. А то как-то ваш код мало соотносится с вопросом.